# How to open a new activity from onClick() of fancybutton?

Tags: android, button

How to open a new activity from `onClick()` of fancybutton.

The fancybutton library that I used is
https://github.com/medyo/fancybuttons, and below is an example image of fancybutton

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the `onClick()` of fancybutton as normal android button. See below:

**Through Java code**

```
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_preview);
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent i = new Intent(currentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
         startActivty(i);

    }
 });
```

**Through xml**

```
<mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
android:id="@+id/btn_preview"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="onClickBtn"/>
```

and in your Activity,add

```
public void onClickBtn(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(currentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivty(i);
}
```